# Первый фрагмент в Navigation всегда вызывается два раза на Android 10

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation-drawer

Есть вот такой вот BottomNavigationView в разметке:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@color/bkg_bottom_bar"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/mwhite"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/mwhite"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="selected"
        />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        />
```

То есть внизу вкладки при нажатии на них меняются фрагменты в MainActivity присваиваю NavGraph:

```
navController.setGraph(R.navigation.mobile_navigation)
navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

Все как положено первым у меня заставка SplashFragment идет он указан в R.navigation.mobile_navigation, но какой бы фрагмент не был указан в app:startDestination в файле mobile_navigation он стабильно вызывается 2 раза. Если еще в разметке указать Graph то 4 раза. Почему не пойму. Можно ли это как то решить без костыля в первом фрагменте? Тут новая информация Похоже срабатывает два раза только на android 10 На Android 8.1, 6, 5.1 сработало 1 раз. Буду еще тестировать.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю поможет или нет, но вот так работает без проблем:

В разметке добавить:

```
   <fragment
    ...
    app:navGraph = "@navigation/mobile_navigation"
    />
```

Потом в Activity где инициализируете NavController :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView

lateinit var navController : NavController

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, 
    R.id.nav_host_fragment)

    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(
            bottomNavigationView,
            navController
        )
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не работает. Стабильный вызов 2 раза на android 10 c другими нормально все вроде.